# which driver should I use to run mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm wondering about which driver is the best between the following :

```
mongodb-csharp driver
simple-mongodb driver
NoRM
```

which one consider the best !>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are even more flavours: the one you call mongodb-csharp is actually two:

- https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp
- https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

The first is a bit more mature and is used widely in the field. The second is a recent development, but is coming from 10gen, the creators of mongodb. Implementation is looking good and is rather like the samus driver. If you need in production something right now, I'm not sure what to advise, but in the long run, I'd go for the 10gen driver.

The one thing that it currently doesn't offer is Linq integration. This could be important to you.

I have no experience with the NORM and simple-mongdb drivers.

Comment: I'm actually using the first right now and I found It pretty cool . but why u advise me to use the 10gen driver instead ?!

Comment: @rahwi:I'm not advising that. I expect that the 10gen driver will be a more future proof choice if you start now. The company that brought us mongodb is backing this project as the driver for the .NET platform. The two are very comparable in design. Switching wouldn't be hard, but I'd definitely not jump now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the official c# driver released by mongoDB.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center

I've been using it and I like it so far.